# how to to create and broadcast a custom token transaction in bsc with php?

Tags: raw-transaction, php

i have custom token on bsc. i use some [kornrunner class](https://github.com/kornrunner) for signing my transaction and broadcast it but i have some problem here. when i send hex to bsc chain, return txid for me but blockHash & blockNumber are null when i search the txid , then  after some minutes the wholl response of txid become null.

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'trans/vendor/autoload.php';
use kornrunner\Ethereum\Transaction;
use kornrunner\Keccak;
use kornrunner\Ethereum\Token;

$nonce    = '22';
$gasPrice = '12a05f200';
$gasLimit = '1300e';
$to       = '6F1580a43FDe8440bB99a40Dc7a295C44fFE5776';
$chainId  = 56;
$privateKey = 'privet key';

$token = new Token;
$ppt  = new Token\PPT;////0x06708529FFbBdee15581Ec8689a0986ac9C89968
$amount = 17;
$hexAmount = $token->hexAmount($ppt, $amount);

$data = $token->getTransferData($to, $hexAmount);
$transaction = new Transaction($nonce, $gasPrice, $gasLimit, $to, '', $data);
$transaction->getRaw($privateKey,$chainId);

$hexTxNew = $transaction->getRaw($privateKey,$chainId);

//////////////////////////////////send for broadcast/////////////////////////////////
 $url = 'https://api.bscscan.com/api';
$fields = [
'module' => 'proxy',
'action' => 'eth_sendRawTransaction',
'hex' => $hexTxNew,
'apikey' => 'myapiKey'
 ];

 $fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 $t = json_decode($result, true);
 var_dump($result);
 
 /// the result in OK and give me tx id then i search it and nothing....
```

i will be appreciated and thankful if someone help me.